# How to modify elements from external JS file?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to split HTML file and separate javascript into an external file. In the HTML file, I have an element `<p id="log">`, which I now access using `document.getElementById("log").innerHTML`.
How to access this element from external JS? 
Is it ok when I just use `document.getElementById("log").innerHTML` in the external JS? Or I need to pass element as parameter to some function like

```
function myFunc(logElement) {
  logElement.innerHTML += "some new data";
}
```

Or there are another common practices?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it's OK. The script from the external file is loaded to the document, as it would be inside the script tags. There's no difference in the execution between inline scripts and external scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you wrote, you are trying to create a separate JS file to access a value inside a HTML tag. If that's all you want to do, just insert a `<script>` tag in the HTML file you want to access the data:

`<script src="file.js"></script>`

From there you use your function to access it. And yes, you can use `document.getElementById("log").innerHTML` as long as you have the script tag in the HTML file you want to access the data.